# A hyperbolic surface is isometric to a pair of pants (the gluing of two identical right-angled hexagons) if it has the correct topology

Tags: differential-topology, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a proof of the following fact:

> Take a hyperbolic surface $S$ with finite area and three (possibly degenerate) geodesic boundary components. If $S$ is diffeomorphic to a pair of pants, then it is **isometric** to a pair of pants.

The following excerpt is taken from Hummel's book *Gromov’s Compactness Theorem for Pseudo-holomorphic Curves* (Lemma IV.3.5, pp. 63-64).

[image: excerpt from Hummel]

The proof boils down to showing that, given three isometries $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\in \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H$ with the relation $\sigma_1\sigma_2=\sigma_3$, the group they generate is determined by the absolute values of their traces, up to conjugation by some isometry and reflection.

Essentially, these isometries correspond to the boundary components under the correspondence $\pi_1(S)\leftrightarrow\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is the deck transformation group of the universal cover $\tilde S\subseteq\mathbb H$ of $S$, while the absolute values of the traces are $\ge 2$ and correspond to the lengths of the boundary components (with some formula).

What I don't understand is why, given $a>1$, $\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ are determined by $t_2:=|\text{tr}(\sigma_2)|$ and $t_3:=|\text{tr}(\sigma_3)|$. It seems to me that the equations $|b+c|=t_2$, $|ab+a^{-1}c|=t_3$ can have two different solutions (up to sign). For instance take $a=2$;
for $t_2=t_3=2$ there are two solutions:
$$\sigma_2=\begin{bmatrix} 2/3 & -1/6 \\ 2/3 & 4/3 \end{bmatrix},\quad
\sigma_3=\begin{bmatrix} 4/3 & -1/3 \\ 1/3 & 2/3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\sigma_2=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 9/2 \\ -2 & 4 \end{bmatrix},\quad
\sigma_3=\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 9 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$
I guess they are conjugated in some obvious way that I don't see, or maybe one of the two groups does not act properly discontinuously...

Comment: Yes, they are conjugated in various ways, and in fact there are many passages in this quote where "conjugacy" is invoked. Do not follow one or the other of those passages?

Comment: How are the two subgroups generated by $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$ conjugated to each other (I mean the ones produced by the two explicit solutions I wrote)?

Comment: I can follow the proof by Hummel, except for the part underlined in red. That part is clearly wrong, as my example shows, but I hope the proof can be fixed in some simple way...

Comment: Certainly a wonderful title.

Comment: Your question is still somewhat confusing. From the highlighted fact that you cite, the context is clearly surfaces-with-boundary. What definition of hyperbolic structure are you using for a surface-with-boundary?

Comment: Hyperbolic structure = complete metric with curvature -1 and geodesic boundaries. The statement asks also that this metric has finite area.

Comment: Incidentally, a much better proof is geometric and is based on a decomposition of a pair of pants in two hyperbolic hexagons. As for the underlined claim, one needs to show that for each hyperbolic pair of pants, lifts $\sigma_i, i=1,2,3$, to $SL(2,R)$, satisfying $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma^{-1}_3=1$ can be chosen so that two traces are positive and one is negative. Maybe the author did verify this earlier in the book, otherwise, the solution indeed is non-unique.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you! I was also thinking of such alternative proof, taking the shortest geodesic segment between two boundary components (or something similar in degenerate cases)... Why do you expect that the "right" isometries should come with traces of different sign?

Comment: @Mizar: I do not expect, I know this. I can find a reference if you like. By the way, you should edit the title of your question to something more transparent such as "hyperbolic pair of pants is determined by the lengths of its cuffs".

Comment: Ah great! The author already proved that a right-angled hexagon (with suitable assumptions for degenerate cases) having consecutive sides $a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3$ is determined by the lenghts of the sides $b_i$. The purpose of this lemma is to show that such surface is a standard pair of pants, i.e. obtained by gluing two hexagons (so the title you suggest could be misleading).

Comment: OK, in any case, it is unclear from the text and you should modify the post to make your question clear. Regardless, there is a purely geometric proof that each hyperbolic PoP can be obtained by gluing two right-angled hexagons. Hint: Connect cuffs $a, b$, then $b, c$, and then $c, a$ by shortest geodesics.

Comment: If you find a simple way to deduce that fact on the signs of traces, please post it :-) Otherwise, just post the hint for an alternative proof, and I will gladly accept it!